# Text and Images in LaTeX

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have LaTeX document with text and images. I added some images in section 2 in the itemize environment. The image that is in section 2 is appearing in section one. I guess the text is adjusting itself wherever it finds space. Following is the code. What shall I do?

```
\section{Introduction} % (fold)
\label{sec:introduction}
Text
% section introduction (end)

\section{A} % (fold)
\label{sec:a}
\beginItem
\item Text

% Image Start
\image{0.2}{ll.png}{L}{fig:1}
% Image End

% Image Start
\image{0.2}{l.png}{C}{fig:2}
% Image End
\item text


 \bFig
\sbsImage{0.2}{l.png}{a}{subFig:1}
\sbsImage{0.2}{ll.png}{b}{subFig:2} 
\eFig{ure, (a) El; (b) Sec}{fig:3
```

I am using macros as:

```
\newcommand{\bFig} {
    \begin{figure}\[h\]
}
\newcommand{\sbsImage}\[4\] {
    \begin{subfigure}\[h\]{.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics\[scale=#1\]{#2}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{#4}
    \end{subfigure}%
}
```

The first image is shown in 1st sec instead of 2, the second image after item 2. This is not showing me the correct image , instead of showing after item 2, shows me after item 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [!htb] after defining image to override default placement.

see this thread:
    https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32598/force-latex-image-to-appear-in-the-section-in-which-its-declared

In my latest LaTeX I did

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{images/myimage.jpg}
\end{center}
\caption{Description for this image~\cite{pic1}.}
\label{pic1}
\end{figure}
```

and this worked.

Comment: How did you use [!htb] ? Try using only [!ht] for instance or only [!h] or [h]. See my edited answer and try this please:)

Comment: Yes, it at corrected at one place, at not at others:(

Comment: Updated check. It just corrected at one place, they are misplaced within the items.

Comment: what is not in a section you want it to be in?

Comment: I have no image in section 1, Images are section 2 in itemize, After 1st there are 2 images (earlier one was shown in section 1, other after item 1, adding [h] resolved it. There are two subfigures after item 2, they are shown after item 3. At other places the image is adjusting itself.

Comment: Put [h] on every item your want to place 'Here', which is what [h] does. Even other stuff, not just images